# Finding volume of cone using triple integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral

I can't understand where I am wrong right here. 
If I have a cone $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ located between $z=0$ and $z=1$, its volume is NOT the following integral:

$$V=\int_{-1}^{1}dx\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}^{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}dy\int_{0}^{1}dz$$

Below you can see the graph of that cone

[image]

So I don't really know where is the mistake in this integral.
I would appreciate your help.

Comment: @DonAntonio This is not the correct integral. The given integral instead describes the volume of a cylinder of height and radius $1$.

Comment: @PeterForeman You're completely right.

Comment: The innermost integral must be $$\int_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}^1$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limits for the integral of the $dy$ part is not correct, as the $1$ in $1 - x^2$ should be $z^2$ instead. As such, the integral for the volume using Cartesian co-ordinates would then be

$$V=\int_{-1}^{1}dx\int_{-\sqrt{z^2 - x^2}}^{\sqrt{z^2 - x^2}}dy\int_{0}^{1}dz \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

This is because the boundary condition is

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
z & = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \\
z^2 & = x^2 + y^2 \\
y^2 & = z^2 - x^2 \\
y & = \pm\sqrt{z^2 - x^2}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Note I would write the integral in the order required to do evaluations from innermost to outermost (i.e., $y$ and $x$ for each circular disk and then $z$ for the sums of volumes of the disks), so it would then instead be

$$V=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-\sqrt{z^2 - x^2}}^{\sqrt{z^2 - x^2}}dydxdz \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand the problem. I just didn't pay enough attention.

Answer (score 0):

The integral you wrote, with the inner integral corrected,  equals, with polar (cylindrical in 3D) coordinates:

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_r^1 r\, dz\,dr\,d\theta=2\pi\int_0^1r(1-r)\,dr=2\pi\left(\frac12-\frac13\right)=\frac\pi3$$

This is after projecting on the $\;z=0\;$ plane.

Comment: Could you explain a little as to why we get $\int_r^1$ for dr?